# Javascript/HTML 5 Canvas Code

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Web Page Design</title>
<head>
<script>
function sayHello() {
//x,y,z
var points = [0,0,0,
              0,0,1,
              1,0,0,
              1,0,1,
              0,1,0,
              0,1,1,
              1,1,1,
              1,1,0];
var indices = [1,2,
               2,3,
               3,4,
               1,4,
               1,5,
               2,6,
               3,7,
               4,8,
               5,6,
               6,7,
               7,8,
               5,8];
var campos = [-1,1,-1];
var camrot = [0,-45,0];
var x_fov = 60;
var y_fov = 60;
var pts = [];
var scrn = [];
var temp;
var canvas = document.getElementById("window");
if (canvas.getContext) {
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   var pts = points.length / 3;
   for (n = 0; n < pts; n++) {
       var c_x = points[n*3];
       var c_y = points[(n*3)+1];
       var c_z = points[(n*3)+2];
       var x_diff = Math.abs(campos[0]-c_x);
       var y_diff = Math.abs(campos[1]-c_y);
       var z_diff = Math.abs(campos[2]-c_z);
       var depth = Math.sqrt(power(x_diff,2)-power(y_diff,2)-
power(z_diff,2));
       var x_rot = toDegrees(Math.atan(y_diff/z_diff));
       var y_rot = toDegrees(Math.atan(x_diff/z_diff));
       if (x_rot < (x_fov/2)+camrot[0]){
           if (x_rot > (x_fov/2)-camrot[0]){
               if (y_rot < (y_fov/2)+camrot[1]){
                   if (y_rot > (y_fov/2)-camrot[1]) {
                       //draw code

                       pts.push(((x_fov/2)-x_rot)/x_fov);
                       pts.push(((y_fov/2)-y_rot)/y_fov);
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   var count = 0;
   for (pt in pts) {

       if ((count % 2) == 0) {
           //if even (x)
           scrn.push(Math.ceil(canvas.width/pt));
       }
       else {
           //if odd (y)
           scrn.push(Math.ceil(canvas.height/pt));
       }
       count++;
   }
   var icount = 0;
   for (ind in indices) {
       if ((icount % 2) == 0) {
           //even
         temp = ind;  
       }
       else {
           //odd
           //take temp and ind and draw lines with pts
           _x = scrn[temp*2];
           _y = scrn[(temp*2)+1];
           ctx.beginPath();
           ctx.moveTo(_x*10, _y*10);
           n_x = scrn[ind*2];
           n_y = scrn[(ind*2)+1];
           ctx.lineTo(n_x*10, n_y*10);
           ctx.closePath();
           ctx.stroke();
       }
   }
}
else {
   document.write("No work");
}
}
function toDegrees(rads) {
return rads * (180 / Math.PI);
}

sayHello();
</script>
<style>#window{border:1px solid red;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="window" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to draw a wireframe cube using javascript and html 5 canvas.  For some reason, it does not work.  I use arrays to turn 3D geometry into 2D points on the screen and connect them via an indices array.  I am sort of trying to replacate the OpenGL library for the web (I understand WebGL already exists) but I want to be able to change the code for performance and ease of use.  This is just a basic bit of code, however the canvas does not even work, as the red border that I applied using a style tag does not work.  I made sure my browser supported html 5 canvas, but nothing works.  I'm assuming its just bad coding and if anyone can figure out what's wrong that would be great, thanks.

Comment: You seem to run the script before DOM is ready which makes for example this line fail: `document.getElementById("window");`. Try to place the script at the bottom of body or use window.onload inside the script.

Comment: I put the code in jsfiddle and its working fine. Red box is shown

Comment: jsfiddle runs the js code after the document is ready by default. In your test page @Mapcat1118, after changing `sayHello()` to `window.onload=sayHello` for example, open the console and debug the errors reported. The first one shown is that `power` is not defined. FYI refer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/5217142 for discussion of `for ... in` loops.

Comment: The script is executing before the body of the page is loaded in the DOM (therefore 'canvas = false).  You may find [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) useful.